# 3 - Dimensional Array PHP insertion

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP array

```
$res = array(

    0 =>array(
      'task' => 'Call with Training',
      'instruction' => 'ins',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study'),

     1 =>array(
      'task' => 'Culture & Values',
      'instruction' => 'ins',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study'),

     2 =>array(
     'task' => 'Call with Training',
      'instruction' => 'ins',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study'),

     3 =>array(
      'task' => 'Call with Training',
      'instruction' => 'ins and training',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study')
);
```

And I am trying to count duplicate keys and group them together and trying to get the result like this:

```
$upd = array(
    'Call with Training' => array(
        0 => array(
              'instruction' => 'ins',
              'color' =>  '#f48718',
              'legend' =>  'Home Study',
              'count' => 2
        ),
        1 => array(
              'instruction' => 'ins and training',
              'color' =>  '#f48718',
              'legend' =>  'Home Study',
              'count' => 1
        )
    ),
    'Culture & Values' => array(
        0 => array(
              'instruction' => 'ins',
              'color' =>  '#f48718',
              'legend' =>  'Home Study',
              'count' => 1
        )
    )
);
```

And my code till now is :

```
foreach($res as $s){
    $key = $s['task'];

    if(isset($upd[$key])) {
        foreach($upd[$key] as $x){
            if($x['task'] === $s['task'] && $x['instruction'] === $s['instruction']){
                $x['count']++;
            }
            else{
                $upd[$key][] = array('task' => $s['task'], 'instruction' => $s['instruction'], 'count' => 1,'color' =>  $s['color'], 'legend' => $s['legend']);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $upd[$key][] = array('task' => $s['task'], 'instruction' => $s['instruction'], 'count' => 1,'color' =>  $s['color'], 'legend' => $s['legend']);
    }

}
```

It would be great if someone can come up help me doing this. Thank you.

Comment: What keys are considered duplicate?

Comment: @u_mulder if task names are same, then there count should be increased. So task name is the key.

Comment: @u_mulder if you see 2nd code block, you can see task name "call with training" has 2 entries. Because they have different "instruction".

Comment: Btw, there can't be same keys in array, so you have to edit your expected results.

Comment: @u_mulder I have edited.

Comment: Here is one solution: https://pastebin.com/k2ck87EL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
// source array
$res = array(

    0 =>array(
      'task' => 'Call with Training',
      'instruction' => 'ins',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study'),

     1 =>array(
      'task' => 'Culture & Values',
      'instruction' => 'ins',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study'),

     2 =>array(
     'task' => 'Call with Training',
      'instruction' => 'ins',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study'),

     3 =>array(
      'task' => 'Call with Training',
      'instruction' => 'ins and training',
      'color' =>  '#f48718',
      'legend' =>  'Home Study')
);
$new = [];
foreach ($res as $v) {
    $task = $v['task'];

    if (empty($new[$task])) {
        $new[$task] = [];
    }

    $ins = $v['instruction'];
    if (!isset($new[$task][$ins])) {
        $v['count'] = 1;
        $new[$task][$ins] = $v;
    } else {
        $new[$task][$ins]['count']++;
    }
}

echo'<pre>Before: ',print_r($new),'</pre>';

// to make keys as numbers - use `array_values`
$new = array_map('array_values', $new);

echo'<pre>After: ',print_r($new),'</pre>';
```

Comment: @u_mulder do you have any idea how to iterate over this array in angular js. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, so no, I have no idea.